# Create struct or class for load data from firestore

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create a **Struct** to load **data** from **Firestore**. But I do not want to use an **array**, I want to use only **Strings** to load the same data every time.

Now I am using this code:

```
var studioHallName: String = ""
var startTimeWeekdays: String = ""
var endTimeWeekdays: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Firestore.firestore().collection("firestore").whereField("id", isEqualTo: hallID).getDocuments() {
        querySnapshot, error in

        if let error = error {

            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

        } else {

            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {

                if let HallName = document.data()["studioHallName"] as? String {
                    self.studioHallName = HallName
                }
                if let hallStartTimeWeekdays = document.data()["startTimeWeekdays"] as? String {
                    self.startTimeWeekdays = hallStartTimeWeekdays
                }
                if let hallEndTimeWeekdays = document.data()["endTimeWeekdays"] as? String {
                    self.endTimeWeekdays = hallEndTimeWeekdays
                }
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }

    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newDetailTableCell", for: indexPath) as! NewDetailTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = studioHallName
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = startTimeWeekdays
    cell.addressLabel.text = endTimeWeekdays

    return cell

}
```

How can I create a **Struct** or **Class** in order to reuse it later? And how can I use this **Struct** or **Class** to load data from **Firestore**?

Comment: May I suggest you read the [Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82) chapter of the Swift book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of options for you, but this is very fundamental stuff, so you should definitely read up on Classes and Structs.

The basic implementation of this Struct would look something like this:

```
struct StudioHallSession { //Just guessing on the name.  I don't have context.

  let studioHallName: String
  let startTime: String
  let endTime: String
}
```

That's really all you need for a basic implementation.  A basic `init` will be inferred unless you need to have custom logic.

As for making the fetch reusable, a very basic implementation would look like this:

```
static func getSession(forHallId hallId: String, _ completion: (_ session: StudioHallSession?)->()) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("firestore").whereField("id", isEqualTo: hallID).getDocuments() {
        querySnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
            if let HallName = document.data()["studioHallName"] as? String {
              self.studioHallName = HallName
            }
            if let hallStartTimeWeekdays = document.data()["startTimeWeekdays"] as? String {
              self.startTimeWeekdays = hallStartTimeWeekdays
            }
            if let hallEndTimeWeekdays = document.data()["endTimeWeekdays"] as? String {
              self.endTimeWeekdays = hallEndTimeWeekdays
            }
          }
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In order to use this function, you would remove that function from your `viewDidLoad` and replace it with this:

```
var studioHallSession: StudioHallSession?

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  StudioHallSession.getSession(forHallId: hallId) { (session) in
    //Check to see if you got a valid session, and assign to your session variable
    if let session = session {
      self.studioHallSession = session
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

Finally, you'd have to modify your tableView method to handle getting info from this session object like so:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = studioHallSession?.studioHallName
cell.descriptionLabel.text = studioHallSession?.startTime
cell.addressLabel.text = studioHallSession?.endTime
```

Of course you'll have to handle situations where you don't find an object in your Firestore, etc.

Comment: Thanks. It helped for me.